# C# (Asp.net MVC 2) Display image from byte[] in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, binary

I need to save picture in my datebase of asp.net mvc application. I created a field in a table MimeType (nvarchar[50]) and ImageData for save the picture in byte[]. I use ado.net. I save the image in a table like this:

```
 private DBAppl db = new DBAppl();
            public void CreateNewCar(newcar Car, HttpPostedFileBase image) 
            {
                    if (image != null)
                        {

                            Car.mimetype = image.ContentType;
                            Car.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                            image.InputStream.Read(Car.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);                    

                        }
                db.AddTonewcars(Car);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Picture normal saved in table. Then I walt to display my image in View. I create method in controller

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int newcarid)
        {
            DBAppl db = new DBAppl();
            newcar car = (from p in db.newcars
                              where p.newcarid == newcarid
                               select p).First();
            return File(car.ImageData, car.mimetype.Trim());
        }
```

In view I inserted this code:

```
<% if (Model.ImageData == null)
{ %>
None
<% }
else
{ %>
<img src="<%= Url.Action("GetImage", "Cars", new { Model.newcarid }) %>" alt="<%: Model.description %>" /> <% } %>
```

But the picture is not loaded, only alt. Help, what I done wrong? I try to use link in sourse code of html-page but a read that picture have error. I looked in mozilla "Information about the page" and see that page have my picture (778 kb) but it is 0px x 0px.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set headers before returning file

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length"("Content-Type", "image/jpeg"));
```

or however you are accessing your headers.

use image/jpeg for jpg files

google for other extensions and file tpes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int newcarid)
        {
            DBAppl db = new DBAppl();
            newcar car = (from p in db.newcars
                              where p.newcarid == newcarid
                               select p).First();
            return File(car.ImageData**.ToArray()**, car.mimetype.Trim());
        }
```

In class:

```
 public void CreateNewCar(newcar Car, HttpPostedFileBase image) 
            {
            **var car = new newcar();**
            if (image != null)
                {

                    car.name = Car.name;
                    car.date = DateTime.Now;
                    car.color = Car.color;
                    car.picmimetype = image.ContentType;

                    int length = image.ContentLength;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                    image.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                    car.ImageData = buffer;

                }
            db.AddTonewcars(car);
        db.SaveChanges();
```